# php(compare two datetimes in a query)

Tags: php, mysql

A user can write his email and subscribe to news, but I want to prevent one IP address from sending more than 5 email addresses per day. I'm inserting date, IP and email to the DB, but I don't know how to compare two datetimes in a query. Can someone help me to write a query?

```
if(isset($_POST["send"])){

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
        $query = 'INSERT INTO subscriber(data, ip, email)
                  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.$email.'" 
                  FROM dual
                  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                     SELECT * FROM subscriber
                     WHERE email="'.$email.'"
                  )';
        $result =  mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
        $msg="Email sent successfully";
    }
    else {
        $msg="Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I think i miss-understood. May be i will be wrong but i think you need this

```
    INSERT INTO iwaki_alphabet (data, ip, email) (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.$email.'" FROM dual where NOT EXISTS ( Select count(email) as c  FROM (
SELECT email FROM iwaki_alphabet  WHERE ip="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'" and DATE(`data`) = CURDATE() group by email) as a having c>5))
```

Just check and confirm me that you need the above thing or something different.